# Given a N×N grid, compute all possible sequences of 5 consecutive spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matrix, grid

Given a N×N grid, where all positions in the grid are marked either has "Yes," "No" or " " (space).

Find all possible sequences in the grid containing 5 consecutive " " (spaces). Here "consecutive spaces" can either be vertical, horizontal or diagonal.

We can assume that the grid is represented as a dictionary, wherein every key of the dictionary represents a position as a co-ordinate and every value represents whether there is a "Yes," "No" or " " on the position.

For example, grid[(1, 2)] = "Yes." Indicates that there is a "Yes" at position (1, 2) on the grid.

We can also assume that the value of N is known in advance.

My initial approach to this problem involved looping through the entire grid from the beginning, checking for horizontal sequences, then vertical sequences and then diagonal sequences. However, this would prove to be inefficient as I would have to continuously re-calculate lengths of the sequences each time, making sure they are equal to 5 as well as checking whether the sequences are consecutive.

I was looking for a more elegant approach, a better way to do this. Is there a Python library that allows for such computations? I have tried looking but didn't find anything that fit the constraints of the problem.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is your effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scipy`; specfically, use the `scipy.ndimage.label` function, which labels connected sequences together.

```
import scipy, scipy.ndimage


# N and grid dictionary are already known
G = scipy.zeros([N,N])
for k, v in grid.iteritems():
    if v.lower() == 'yes':
        G[tuple(k)] = 1
    elif v.lower() == 'no':
        G[tuple(k)] = -1

def get_consecutive_spaces(G, chain=5):

    sequences = []

    # Generate a pattern for each directional sequence. (1) Horizontal,
    # (2) vertical, (3) top-left to bottom-right diagonal, (4) bottom-left
    # to top-right diagonal
    patterns = [scipy.ndimage.label(G == 0, structure = scipy.array([[0,0,0],
                                                                     [1,1,1],
                                                                     [0,0,0]])),
                scipy.ndimage.label(G == 0, structure = scipy.array([[0,1,0],
                                                                     [0,1,0],
                                                                     [0,1,0]])),
                scipy.ndimage.label(G == 0, structure = scipy.array([[1,0,0],
                                                                     [0,1,0],
                                                                     [0,0,1]])),
                scipy.ndimage.label(G == 0, structure = scipy.array([[0,0,1],
                                                                     [0,1,0],
                                                                     [1,0,0]]))]

    # Loop over patterns, then find any labelled sequence >= a size of chain=5
    for lab_arr, n in patterns:
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            b = lab_arr == i
            b_inds = scipy.where(b)
            if len(b_inds[0]) < chain:
                continue

            sequences.append((tuple(b_inds[0]), tuple(b_inds[1])))

    return sequences
```

E.g.

```
>>> G = scipy.sign(scipy.random.random([12,12]) - 0.5)*(scipy.random.random([12,12]) < 0.5)
>>> print G
[[-0.  1. -1.  1.  1. -1.  1.  0. -0.  1.  0. -0.]
 [ 1.  1. -0. -0. -1.  1.  1. -1. -1.  1. -0. -1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1. -0.  0.  0.  0. -0.  0.]
 [ 1. -0. -1.  0. -1. -0.  1.  0. -0. -0. -0.  1.]
 [-0.  1. -1.  1. -0. -0. -1. -0.  1.  1. -0.  0.]
 [ 0. -1.  1. -0.  1.  0. -0. -1. -1. -0.  0. -1.]
 [-1. -0.  0. -1. -1. -0. -1.  0.  0.  0. -1.  0.]
 [-0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1. -1.  0. -0. -1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1. -1. -1.  0.  0. -1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [-0.  0.  0. -1. -0. -1.  1. -0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]
 [-1.  1. -1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [-1.  1. -0.  0. -1.  0. -0. -1.  1. -1. -0.  0.]]

>>> sequences = get_consecutive_spaces(G)
>>> for s in sequences: print s
((2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11))
((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10))
((6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), (11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11))
((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), (11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4))
((2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (6, 5, 4, 3, 2))
((4, 5, 6, 7, 8), (11, 10, 9, 8, 7))
```

[image]

> Note, returns sequences greater or equal to chain; does not restrict itself to sequences of only 5 in length. To change it to only a length of 5 is a trivial fix.